# How to use JSR-223 to get Scala interpreter in sbt console?

Tags: scala, sbt, jsr223, scala-2.11

In the sbt console, sbt version 0.13.5, Scala version 2.11.1, I can get `javax.script.ScriptEngine` for Scala:

```
scala> val engine = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
engine: javax.script.ScriptEngine = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain@bf78a9
```

However, I can't use it:

```
scala> engine.eval("3")
[init] error: error while loading Object, Missing dependency 'object scala in compiler mirror', required by /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class)

Failed to initialize compiler: object scala in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala in compiler mirror not found.
  at ...
```

[According to the SBT FAQ](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/faq#how-do-i-use-the-scala-interpreter-in-my-code), I am supposed to do some magic with a `Settings`, and then pass it into my `Interpreter`'s constructor. However, I'm not directly creating an `Interpreter` (and it's not even clear if I'm indirectly creating it, as the engine object is an `IMain`).

Is there some way for the Scala `ScriptEngine` to work on the SBT console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast your engine to `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain`, which will give you an access to the `settings`. Then you can use `embeddedDefaults` to set a classpath as [it was mentioned in the FAQ](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Faq.html#How+do+I+use+the+Scala+interpreter+in+my+code?). Just do it before call to the `eval` method.

```
val engine = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
val settings = engine.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain].settings
// MyScalaClass is just any class in your project
settings.embeddedDefaults[MyScalaClass]
```

Given that you should be able to run `eval`, e.g.

```
scala> engine.eval("10")
res3: Object = 10
```

The reason is more or less explained in the [gist linked from the FAQ](https://gist.github.com/harrah/404272). Basically, when creating an interpreter using `getEngineByName("scala")`, the `java.class.path` is used and it contains only `sbt-launch.jar`. Using the trick with `embeddedDefaults` sets the class path to the correct value (you can check the `settings` before and after a call to the `embeddedDefaults`).

Comment: For completeness, `sbt -Dscala.usejavacp=true console` makes getEngine fail. I think the change for jsr223 made classpath tweaks that deserve review. Thx for the gist link, I hadn't seen the history.