# How to add symbols into a parsed AST?

Tags: scala, reflection, macros

(This is loosely related to [Scala script in 2.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373551/scala-script-in-2-11) and [Generating a class from string and instantiating it in Scala 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122939/generating-a-class-from-string-and-instantiating-it-in-scala-2-10)).

In the code below I have a code parsed runtime using Toolbox into a corresponding AST. How can add symbol definitions (`prefix` in the code below) to the AST so that those symbols can be used in the expression tree?

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object Main extends App {

  val cm = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val tb = cm.mkToolBox()

  val expr = tb.parse("println(i)")

  val build = internal.reificationSupport

  val prefix = build.setInfo(build.newFreeTerm("i", 2), typeOf[Int])

  // TODO: add prefix before expr by some AST manipulation

  tb.eval(expr)
}
```

Comment: You need to traverse `expr` using a subclass of `Traverser` and then for all occurrences of `i` (i.e. Idents that say `i`) call `tree.setSymbol(prefix)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could build `expr` with the correct symbols to begin with, e.g. something like `q"println($prefix)"`.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Thanks, I will try the Traverser and post results here (if it works, you or I can post it as a full answer). Building with correct symbols seems difficult, as the expr is a script edited by users. I therefore want its syntax to be as natural as possible, using $xxx for predefined variables is possible, but if there is other solution, I will prefer it.