# Scala JSR223 script using JMeter/Java context

Tags: java, scala, jmeter, jsr223, scriptengine

[Scala JSR223 script support since 2.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373551/scala-script-in-2-11)

> ```
> e.eval("""s"a is $a, s is $s"""")
> ```

I added Scala 2.13 jars and tried to execute script, it can display constants in response

But I can't add JMeter's bind variables as `log`, I tried with:

```
log.info(a);
$log.info(a);
```

Or can't print values to log, tried also

```
var a:Int =  10
println(a)
```

JMeter's [bindings](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/4fa9dd698e31d3d4c2c37b99d0d6c484e7b2d723/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.java) code:

> ```
>  Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
>  final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JSR223_INIT_FILE);
>  bindings.put("log", logger); // $NON-NLS-1$ (this name is fixed)       
>  engine.eval(reader, bindings);
> ```

Tried also using bindings but it isn't in context

```
bindings.get("log").info("aa");
```

Exception

```
ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: not found: value bindings
```

How can I submit Scala JSR223 script using JMeter/Java bindings variables?

**EDIT**

Open [Scala issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11691) JSR223 - Engine ignores bindings parameters

Comment: Odd. When trying this out myself, I see that there are no registered ScriptEngineFactory instances at all.

Comment: @MarkKegel did you add latest jars to classpath?

Comment: D'oh. That was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the issue is that injected bindings are seen by the Scala script engine as having a type of `Any`. To use the injected bindings you either have to cast them to the appropriate type on every use, or you need to inject them as a 'shadow binding' and then re-bind in-engine using the appropriate type.

Here is my `Main.scala`, where I demonstrate the latter approach:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object Main extends App {

  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("main")

  val e = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
  e.put("a", 1)
  e.put("s", "String")

  // Since the variable will have a type of Object, inject under a different name, and then bind to the
  // "correct" name using eval.
  e.put("logInjected", logger)

  println(e.eval(""" s"a is $a, s is $s" """))
  println(e.eval(""" logInjected.toString """))

  e.eval(""" val log = logInjected.asInstanceOf[org.slf4j.Logger] """)
  e.eval(""" log.info("hello from injected logger") """)

  e.eval(
    """ // Or can you do this
      | import org.slf4j.Logger
      | import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
      |
      | val l = LoggerFactory.getLogger("script")
      |
      | l.error("hello from script")
      |
      |""".stripMargin)
}
```

And my `build.sbt` I used to:

```
name := "s213"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.13.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.3.0-alpha4"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "2.0.0-alpha0"
```

The output from running `Main` will be:

```
a is 1, s is String
Logger[main]
[main] INFO  main - hello from injected logger 
[main] ERROR script - hello from script
```

Comment: So variables added to `bindings` are ignored/can't be used in scala when using `engine.eval(reader, bindings)`? Isn't it a bug?